# C++ function pointer syntax. Why does (*) work but * not?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a program for an assignment for a post fix calculator.  There are bonus points if I can do it without using an if statement (no switch or while or any comparisons).  I was reading about function pointers and came up with the following code:

```
int main(){
    unordered_map<char,int*(int,int)> m;
    m.insert({'+',[](int const a, int const b){return a+b;}});
}
```

This doesn't work.

However this does:

```
int main(){
    unordered_map<char,int(*)(int,int)> m;
    m.insert({'+',[](int const a, int const b){return a+b;}});
}
```

Why are `(*)` and `*` different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of

```
int* (int,int)
```

is function taking `(int, int)` and returning `int*`, i.e. a pointer to `int`. On the other hand, the type of

```
int (*) (int, int)
```

is pointer to function taking `(int, int)` and returning `int`. So they are different declarations. In your map you insert types that are decay-able to the latter, not the former, and that's why the latter code works but not the former.

Useful: http://www.cdecl.org/

Super useful: [The clockwise/Spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Answer (score 3):

Without the parens, the `int*` is parsed as just "pointer to int", and the rest of the code just doesn't work.

With the parens, `int (*)` means "pointer to function returning an int" instead, and the parens (and stuff they enclose) specify the arguments to that function, so it all parses as what you want.